# Higgs boson positive parity, and zero spin

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, standard-model, higgs, parity

Can we predict the positive parity, and zero spin of the Higgs boson from
the decay mode:  →

Comment: Recall the pseudoscalar neutral pion *also* goes to two photons!

Answer (score 2):

*Predict*  is the function of models. Yes, the present s[tandard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  predicts  a single Higgs boson excitation of the Higgs field, with zero spin and + parity,   and it calculates for it  a probability to decay into two photons.

Experiments either validate models , or falsify them. The present status of experiments [validates the standard model](http://cds.cern.ch/record/2285863) for the Higgs decay to two photons.